# Values not loading during initial loading of the observable values

Tags: angular, observable, return-value

In an Angular application I want to load the menus dynamically from the database(.NEt Core project). For this I created an API service to get the data in json-format. To request this json format from the frontend, I'm using a service in the `workout.service.ts`-file (I tried it with and without an observable but obtained the same result).

To load the menus I used `menu.service.ts`-file in which the function `getVerticalMenuItems()` is used to load the vertical menus which is not working during the initialization;

Here I use the method `resultmenu.push` to transform the data into below format:

```
export const verticalMenuItems = [
  new Menu(1, 'Dashboard', '/', null, 'dashboard', null, false, 0),
  new Menu(100, 'Action', '/actions', null, 'extension', null, false, 0)]
```

The vertical menu upload, we use `vertical-menu.component.ts` (I persume the problem arises here which always shows the Array[0]=null value)

## menu.modal.ts

```
export class Menu {
    constructor(public id: number,
                public title: string,
                public routerLink: string,
                public href: string,
                public icon: string,
                public target: string,
                public hasSubMenu: boolean,
                public parentId: number) { }
}
```

## workout.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { User } from './models/user.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Menu } from './theme/components/menu/menu.model';

@Injectable()
export class WorkoutService {


private headers: HttpHeaders;

  private menuUrl: string = 'https://localhost:44355/api/Menus';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
this.headers= new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8});}

  // Get Menus
  public getMenus() {return this.http.get(this.menuUrl, { headers: this.headers }).map((response: Response) => {     
      return response;
    });

  }


}
```

## menu.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class MenuService {
  my_menu: Array<Menu>;

  constructor(private location:Location,
              private router: Router,
              private workoutService: WorkoutService) { } 



// for vertical Menu items loading
 public getVerticalMenuItems(): Array<Menu> {  
    const resultMenu: Array<Menu>=[];       
    this.workoutService.getMenus()
       .subscribe(
       (data:any) => {       
        data.forEach(i => {
          resultMenu.push(new Menu(i.id, i.title, i.routerLink, i.href, i.icon, i.target, i.hasSubMenu, i.parentId))
        })
        console.log(resultMenu);
      }
    );

    console.log(resultMenu);
    console.log(verticalMenuItems);
    return resultMenu;
    //return verticalMenuItems; -- NOTE: old working code taken from Gradus theme templates ;(working code)

  }

// working code
  public getHorizontalMenuItems(): Array<Menu> {
      return horizontalMenuItems;
  }


public expandActiveSubMenu(menu: Observable<Menu[]>){
      let url = this.location.path();
      let routerLink = url; // url.substring(1, url.length);
      let activeMenuItem = menu.map(items=>items.filter(item => item.routerLink === routerLink));
      if(activeMenuItem[0]){
        let menuItem = activeMenuItem[0];
        while (menuItem.parentId != 0){  
          let parentMenuItem = menu.map(items=>items.filter(item => item.id == menuItem.parentId)[0]);
          menuItem = parentMenuItem;
          this.toggleMenuItem(menuItem.id);
        }
      }
  }

  public toggleMenuItem(menuId){
    let menuItem = document.getElementById('menu-item-'+menuId);
    let subMenu = document.getElementById('sub-menu-'+menuId);  
    if(subMenu){
      if(subMenu.classList.contains('show')){
        subMenu.classList.remove('show');
        menuItem.classList.remove('expanded');
      }
      else{
        subMenu.classList.add('show');
        menuItem.classList.add('expanded');
      }      
    }
  }

  public closeOtherSubMenus(menu: Array<Menu>, menuId) {
    debugger;
    let currentMenuItem = menu.filter(item => item.id == menuId)[0]; 
    if(currentMenuItem.parentId == 0 && !currentMenuItem.target){
      menu.forEach(item => {
        if(item.id != menuId){
          let subMenu = document.getElementById('sub-menu-'+item.id);
          let menuItem = document.getElementById('menu-item-'+item.id);
          if(subMenu){
            if(subMenu.classList.contains('show')){
              subMenu.classList.remove('show');
              menuItem.classList.remove('expanded');
            }              
          } 
        }
      });
    }
```

## vertical-menu.component.ts

```js
export class VerticalMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() resultMenu: Array<Menu> = [];

  /***************************************
  * MOVED THE NEW INPUTS TO HERE
  ****************************************/
  @Input()
  set menuItems(items: Menu[]) {
    this._menuItemsLoaded$.next(items);
  }
  _menuItemsLoaded$: ReplaySubject<Menu[]> = new ReplaySubject<Menu[]>(1);

  // We must save the received items and also emit it
  @Input() 
  set menuParentId(items: number) {
    this._menuParentIdLoaded$.next(items);
  }
  _menuParentIdLoaded$: ReplaySubject<number> = 
  new ReplaySubject<number>(1);

  /***************************************
  * END OF NEW INPUTS
  ****************************************/

  @Output() onClickMenuItem: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  parentMenu: Array<any>;
  public settings: Settings;

  constructor(public appSettings: AppSettings, public menuService: MenuService, public router: Router) {
    this.settings = this.appSettings.settings;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  /***************************************
   * FIXED THE FILTERS INSIDE THE PIPES
   ****************************************/
    combineLatest(
      this._menuItemsLoaded$.pipe(
            filter(Boolean), 
            filter((i) => !!i.length), 
            debounceTime(300)),
      this._menuParentIdLoaded$.pipe(
            // for _menuParentId (exclusively) we cannot use 
            // filter(Boolean) here, or the 0 values will be blocked
            filter((i) => i !== null && i !== undefined),
            debounceTime(300)),
    ).subscribe(([menuItems, parentId]) => 
      this.parentMenu = menuItems.filter(item => item.parentId == parentId)
    );
  }

  // as we're using some subjects, we must finalize
  // them in case this component is eventually destroyed
  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this._menuItemsLoaded$ && !this._menuItemsLoaded$.closed) {
      this._menuItemsLoaded$.complete();
    }

    if (this._menuParentIdLoaded$ && !this._menuParentIdLoaded$.closed) {
      this._menuParentIdLoaded$.complete();
    }
  }

    //ngOnChanges() {
    //  if (this.menuItems == null) {
    //    this.parentMenu = null;
    //  }
    //  this.parentMenu = this.menuItems.filter(item => item.parentId == this.menuParentId);
    //  console.log(this.parentMenu);
    //}


    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          if (this.settings.fixedHeader) {
            let mainContent = document.getElementById('main-content');
            if (mainContent) {
              mainContent.scrollTop = 0;
            }
          }
          else {
            document.getElementsByClassName('mat-drawer-content')[0].scrollTop = 0;
          }
        }
      });
    }

    onClick(menuId) {
      /*************************************
       * Import take operator from 'rxjs/operators'
       * As part of the changes, the values that we need are
       * all on `_menuItemsLoaded$` ReplaySubject. 
       *************************************/
      combineLatest(this._menuItemsLoaded$).pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(([items]) => {
          this.menuService.toggleMenuItem(menuId);
          this.menuService.closeOtherSubMenus(items, menuId);
          this.onClickMenuItem.emit(menuId);
        }
    }


}
```

## vertical-menu.component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let menu of parentMenu" class="menu-item">
    <a *ngIf="menu.routerLink && menu.hasSubMenu" mat-button 
        fxLayout="row" [fxLayoutAlign]="(settings.menuType=='default') ? 'start center' : 'center center'"
        [routerLink]="[menu.routerLink]" routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
        [matTooltip]="menu.title" matTooltipPosition="after" [matTooltipDisabled]="(settings.menuType=='mini') ? 'false' : 'true'"
        (click)="onClick(menu.id)" [id]="'menu-item-'+menu.id">
        <mat-icon class="menu-icon">{{menu.icon}}</mat-icon>
        <span class="menu-title">{{menu.title}}</span>  <!--  !menu.hasSubMenu--> 
    </a>
    <a *ngIf="menu.href && !menu.subMenu && !menu.hasSubMenu" mat-button 
        fxLayout="row" [fxLayoutAlign]="(settings.menuType=='default') ? 'start center' : 'center center'"
        [attr.href]="menu.href || ''" [attr.target]="menu.target || ''"
        [matTooltip]="menu.title" matTooltipPosition="after" [matTooltipDisabled]="(settings.menuType=='mini') ? 'false' : 'true'"
        (click)="onClick(menu.id)" [id]="'menu-item-'+menu.id">
        <mat-icon class="menu-icon">{{menu.icon}}</mat-icon>
        <span class="menu-title">{{menu.title}}</span>        
    </a>
    <a *ngIf="menu.hasSubMenu" mat-button 
        fxLayout="row" [fxLayoutAlign]="(settings.menuType=='default') ? 'start center' : 'center center'"
        [matTooltip]="menu.title" matTooltipPosition="after" [matTooltipDisabled]="(settings.menuType=='mini') ? 'false' : 'true'"
        (click)="onClick(menu.id)" [id]="'menu-item-'+menu.id">
        <mat-icon class="menu-icon">{{menu.icon}}</mat-icon>
        <span class="menu-title">{{menu.title}}</span>
        <mat-icon class="menu-expand-icon transition-2">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
    </a>

    <div *ngIf="menu.hasSubMenu" class="sub-menu" [id]="'sub-menu-'+menu.id"> 
        <app-vertical-menu [menuItems]="_menuItemsLoaded$ | async" [menuParentId]="menu.id" (onClickMenuItem)="updatePS($event)"></app-vertical-menu>

     <!-- <app-vertical-menu (onClickMenuItem)="updatePS($event)"
                     [menuItems]="{menuItems: _menuItemsLoaded$ | async, parentId: 0}">
      </app-vertical-menu> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

## sidenav.component.html

```html
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="user-block transition-2" [class.show]="settings.sidenavUserBlock"> 
    <div [fxLayout]="(settings.menuType != 'default') ? 'column' : 'row'" 
         [fxLayoutAlign]="(settings.menuType != 'default') ? 'center center' : 'space-around center'" class="user-info-wrapper">
        <img [src]="userImage" alt="user-image">
        <div class="user-info">
            <p class="name">Emilio Verdines</p>
            <p *ngIf="settings.menuType == 'default'" class="position">Web developer <br> <small class="muted-text">Member since May. 2016</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="settings.menuType != 'mini'" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" class="w-100 muted-text">
        <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>person_outline</mat-icon></button>
        <a mat-icon-button routerLink="/mailbox">
            <mat-icon>mail_outline</mat-icon>
        </a>
        <a mat-icon-button routerLink="/login">
            <mat-icon>power_settings_new</mat-icon>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<perfect-scrollbar #sidenavPS class="sidenav-menu-outer" [class.user-block-show]="settings.sidenavUserBlock">   
    <span *ngIf="!menuItems">loading....</span>
    <app-vertical-menu [menuItems]="menuItems" [menuParentId]="0" (onClickMenuItem)="updatePS($event)"></app-vertical-menu> 
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

## sidenav.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [MenuService]
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('sidenavPS') sidenavPS: PerfectScrollbarComponent;
  public userImage = '../assets/img/users/user.jpg';
  public menuItems: Array<any>;
  public settings: Settings;
  constructor(public appSettings: AppSettings, public menuService: MenuService) {
    this.settings = this.appSettings.settings;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    this.menuItems = this.menuService.getVerticalMenuItems();
  }

  ngOnChange() {
    debugger;
    this.menuItems = this.menuService.getVerticalMenuItems();
  }

  public closeSubMenus() {
    const menu = document.querySelector('.sidenav-menu-outer');
    if (menu) {
      for (let i = 0; i < menu.children[0].children.length; i++) {
        const child = menu.children[0].children[i];
        if (child) {
          if (child.children[0].classList.contains('expanded')) {
            child.children[0].classList.remove('expanded');
            child.children[1].classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public updatePS(e) {
    this.sidenavPS.directiveRef.update();
  }
```

## dynamic-menu.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import { Menu } from '../../theme/components/menu/menu.model';
import { MenuService } from '../../theme/components/menu/menu.service';
import { DynamicMenuService } from './dynamic-menu.service';
import { AppSettings } from '../../app.settings';
import { Settings } from '../../app.settings.model';
import { VerticalMenuComponent } from '../../theme/components/menu/vertical-menu/vertical-menu.component';
import { listTransition } from '../../theme/utils/app-animation';
import { combineLatest, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-menu',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-menu.component.html',
  providers: [ DynamicMenuService, MenuService ],
  animations: [ listTransition ],
  host: {
    '[@listTransition]': ''
  }
})
export class DynamicMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  settings: Settings;
  menuItems:Array<Menu>;
  _menuItems$: Observable<Menu[]>;
  public icons = ['home','person', 'card_travel', 'delete', 'event', 'favorite', 'help' ]
  public form:FormGroup;
  constructor(public appSettings:AppSettings, 
              public formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
              public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
              private menuService:MenuService,
              private dynamicMenuService:DynamicMenuService) {
    this.settings = this.appSettings.settings; 
    this._menuItems$ = this.menuService.getVerticalMenuItems()
        .pipe(tap((menuItems: Menu) => this.menuItems = menuItems));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      'title': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])],
      'icon': null,
      'routerLink': ['', Validators.required],    
      'href': ['', Validators.required],            
      'target': null,
      'hasSubMenu': false,
      'parentId': 0
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.form.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).subscribe(menu => {  
      if(menu.routerLink && menu.routerLink != ''){
        this.form.controls['href'].setValue(null);
        this.form.controls['href'].disable();
        this.form.controls['href'].clearValidators();
        this.form.controls['target'].setValue(null);
        this.form.controls['target'].disable();
      }
      else{
        this.form.controls['href'].enable();
        this.form.controls['href'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
        this.form.controls['target'].enable();
      }
      this.form.controls['href'].updateValueAndValidity();

      if(menu.href && menu.href != ''){
        this.form.controls['routerLink'].setValue(null);
        this.form.controls['routerLink'].disable();
        this.form.controls['routerLink'].clearValidators();
        this.form.controls['hasSubMenu'].setValue(false);
        this.form.controls['hasSubMenu'].disable();
      }
      else{
        this.form.controls['routerLink'].enable();
        this.form.controls['routerLink'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
        this.form.controls['hasSubMenu'].enable();
      }
      this.form.controls['routerLink'].updateValueAndValidity();
    })
  }

  onSubmit(menu:Menu):void {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.dynamicMenuService.addNewMenuItem(VerticalMenuComponent, this.menuItems, menu);
      this.snackBar.open('New menu item added successfully!', null, {
        duration: 2000,
      });
      this.form.reset({
        hasSubMenu:false,
        parentId:0
      });    
    } 
  } 

}
```

## dynamic-menu.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable, Injector, ComponentFactoryResolver, ApplicationRef, EmbeddedViewRef } from '@angular/core';
import { VerticalMenuComponent } from '../../theme/components/menu/vertical-menu/vertical-menu.component';
import { Menu } from '../../theme/components/menu/menu.model';

@Injectable()
export class DynamicMenuService {

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
                private applicationRef: ApplicationRef,
                private injector: Injector) { }     

    addNewMenuItem(component: any, menuItems:Array<Menu>, menuItem) {

        const lastId = menuItems[menuItems.length-1].id;
        const newMenuItem = new Menu(lastId+1, menuItem['title'], menuItem['routerLink'], menuItem['href'], menuItem['icon'], menuItem['target'], menuItem['hasSubMenu'], parseInt(menuItem['parentId']));

        menuItems.push(newMenuItem);
        let item = menuItems.filter(item=>item.id == newMenuItem.parentId)[0];
        if(item) item.hasSubMenu = true;  

        const componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
            .resolveComponentFactory(component)
            .create(this.injector);        

        this.applicationRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);

        let instance = <VerticalMenuComponent>componentRef.instance;
        instance.menuItems = menuItems;
        instance.menuParentId = 0;

        const elem = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

        const sidenav = document.getElementById('sidenav-menu-outer');        
        sidenav.replaceChild(elem, sidenav.children[0]);     

    } 
}
```

Check the image for further information, which shows the array null due to subscribe delay [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49nqX.png)
The duplication error,shown in below  link
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4paBH.png)
new error with tap binding
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnpaG.png)

Resultant Output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExKGl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'd change a few things in the code.

### The usage of `<vertical-menu>`

Instead of:

```html
<app-vertical-menu [menuItems]="menuItems" [menuParentId]="0" (onClickMenuItem)="updatePS($event)"></app-vertical-menu>
```

I'd do:

```html
<app-vertical-menu [menuItems]="_menuItems$ | async" [menuParentId]="0" (onClickMenuItem)="updatePS($event)"></app-vertical-menu>
```

The changing of `menuItems` to `_menuItems$` is merely cosmetic, to indicate that it will be an observable, from now on. The real change is the `async` pipe.

### In the typescript code that calls `menuService`

```js
_menuItems$: Observable<Menu>;

ngOnInit() {
  this._menuItems$ = this.menuService.getVerticalMenuItems();
}
```

### MenuService

```js
import {filter, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

...

getVerticalMenuItems(): Observable<Menu[]> {  

  return this.workoutService.getMenus().pipe(
    // this will avoid null/undefined values
    filter(Boolean),
    // this will avoid empty arrays comming from getMenus()
    // just comment it if empty arrays are allowed here
    filter(data => !!data.length),
    // here we're building the Menu array
    map((data:any) => data.map(i => new Menu(i.id, i.title, 
                                             i.routerLink, i.href,
                                             i.icon, i.target, 
                                             i.hasSubMenu, i.parentId))
  ); // here we're closing the pipe

}
```

By doing things like this, we'll be delegating to the `async` pipe the responsibility of subscribing and unsubscribing to the menu service.

I'm not sure what the `getMenu()` is doing here. Is it going to grab menu data from the server? If so, isn't it more performant to cache menu data in the service when the app starts instead of going to the server every time? Just a guess, because I'm not fully aware of how you built up the things in your app.

## UPDATE

As I missed there was another error, I'm adding some more changes in other components.

### VerticalMenuComponent

In that component, you have:

```js
@Input('menuItems') menuItems;
@Input('menuParentId') menuParentId;

...

ngOnInit() {
  this.parentMenu = this.menuItems.filter(item => item.parentId == this.menuParentId); -- not working??
}
```

To successfully initialize `parentMenu`, you must be sure that both `menuItems` and `menuParentId` are loaded. It's not safe to do it like it's being done, inside `OnInit`. The way I'm gonna propose is very reliable IMO (I use it in some components of mine) and use the powerful API of RxJs.

**UPDATED 2 (The `filter(Boolean)` cannot be used for menuParentId):**

```js
// We must save the received items and also emit it
@Input() 
set menuItems(items: Menu[]) {
  this._menuItemsLoaded$.next(items);
}
private _menuItemsLoaded$: ReplaySubject<Menu[]> = new ReplaySubject<Menu[]>(1);

// We must save the received items and also emit it
@Input() 
set menuParentId(items: number) {
  this._menuParentIdLoaded$.next(items);
}
private _menuParentIdLoaded$: ReplaySubject<number> = 
  new ReplaySubject<number>(1);

...

ngOnInit() {
  combineLatest(
    this._menuItemsLoaded$.pipe(
          filter(Boolean), 
          filter((_) => !!_.length), 
          debounceTime(300)),
    this._menuParentIdLoaded$.pipe(
          // for _menuParentId (exclusively) we cannot use 
          // filter(Boolean) here, or the 0 values will be blocked
          filter((_) => _ !== null && _ !== undefined),
          debounceTime(300)),
  ).subscribe(([menuItems, parentId]) => 
    this.parentMenu = menuItems.filter(item => item.parentId == parentId)
  );
}

// as we're using some subjects, we must finalize
// them in case this component is eventually destroyed
ngOnDestroy() {
  if(this._menuItemsLoaded$ && !this._menuItemsLoaded$.closed) {
    this._menuItemsLoaded$.complete();
  }

  if(this._menuParentIdLoaded$ && !this._menuParentIdLoaded$.closed) {
    this._menuParentIdLoaded$.complete();
  }
}
```

### Another approach

If you think the approach above is kind of overwhelming (which I agree, but I think it's also very helpful to get used to RxJs), and you have full control over the API of your `VerticalMenuComponent` and its `@Input()`'s, you can think of creating a menu component data interface and pass just one parameter:

```js
export interface VerticalMenuComponentData {
  menuItems: Menu[];
  parentId: number;
}

...

// We must save the received items and also emit it
@Input() 
get verticalMenuComponentData: VerticalMenuComponentData { return this._verticalMenuComponentData; }
set verticalMenuComponentData(data: VerticalMenuComponentData) {
  this._verticalMenuComponentData = data;

  // You don't need to call anything inside ngOnInit
  this.parentMenu = data && data.menuItems && data.parentId 
    ? data.menuItems.filter(item => item.parentId == data.parentId) 
    : [];
}
private _verticalMenuComponentData: VerticalMenuComponentData;
```

And then you should change a little bit the template:

```html
<app-vertical-menu (onClickMenuItem)="updatePS($event)"
                   [menuItems]="{menuItems: _menuItems$ | async, parentId: 0}">
</app-vertical-menu>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192115/discussion-on-answer-by-jpavel-values-not-loading-during-initial-loading-of-the).

Comment: Method 1 is working and edited as per new instructions. Thank you.. @jpavel

Answer (score 1):

When calling subscribe() your code does not stop to wait for the server to respond. Instead it continues to execute the rest of `getVerticalMenuItems()`. As soon as the http request is finished, the function you put as parameter of the `subscribe()` is executed. But this can be a second or two later. So your `console.log(--END OF SUBSCRIBE---)` is actually not true, it's not the end of the `subscribe()`, the `subscribe()` has not yet finished at this point in execution.

What you can do now: 
Make resultMenu a component variable and save the data in there. Then in your html, you can use that variable normally, e.g.:

```
<ul *ngFor="let menu of resultMenu">
  <li>
    //other code
    {{menu.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Angular will detect that your `this.resultMenu` has changed and will update the view automatically (unless change detection is set to onPush, then you have to do that). You will see that your menu will appear as soon as the server responds.

If you have to do something with the received data before displaying it, you have to implement ngOnChanges and do that there. That is called, whenever an input of a component has changed.

[Here is a Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-subscribe-to-servercall), check out console logs

Comment: Thanks for comments @Jeremy. Here I used console.log(--END OF SUBSCRIBE---) just as a log for identification, Here I am displaying the  **verticalMenuItems ** which was the original menu. I need to convert the dynamic menu to the same format (so resultMenu.Push is provided). As per information i have to replace every verticalMenuItems with resultMenu, right?

Comment: check the image description

Comment: replaced the resultMenu to this.resultMenu , but still old problem

Comment: Yes, because at the time when ngOnInit() of VerticalMenuComponent is executed, the server has not yet responded! It's to early. Did you put the html of my answer into VerticalMenuComponent and it didn't display anything? Obviously you have to bind this.resultMenu to the input of VerticalMenuComponent in order to make that work.

Comment: still same status. Since this is a Gradus template, there are much developer based specifications, say verticalMenuItem in defined in main.js  too.

Comment: See demo. It works as I described. Or are we talking about something else?

Comment: @SarathMohandas, are you using onPush strategy in your component (any parent of the menu component or the menu component itself)?

Comment: By the way, I agree with @JeremyBenks. Without knowing what you're doing in your component, it seems very strange the calling of `getVerticalMenuItems()`. Who is getting the returned value? Where do you intend to use it?

Comment: console.log takes a reference to the array you're passing it. At the moment it's called, it's probably empty. But as the console checks the reference, when the value arrives, it prints it out on the console. To see the real value at the moment the console.log is called, you can do `console.log(JSON.stringify(resultMenu));`

Comment: @jpavel check the html components, which was working for the code verticalMenuItems; Thanks, Jermy that demo is working perfectly for another project .

Comment: @SarathMohandas, you need to change a little bit your menu service. I'll right an answer about it because there will be not enough space here.

Comment: the demo was nice , and i implemented without APi's , Thanks @JeremyBenks

Comment: Still duplication... Is thete anyproblem in side nav component

Comment: What do you mean: 'Still dublication'? As far as I can see, my stack blitz works. Or not?